# error on ccavenue payment gateway plugins

Tags: java, javascript, php, wordpress

hiii I activate ccavenue payment gateway plugin. but when I click the checkout, check out page open with blank and redirect another page..How can I fix this and connect to my payment gate way? But the problem is still there. ccavnue plugins deactivated then as well as work all page one by one. So tell what i can do..
show error:- plugins/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woo commerce/index.php on line 26.....

So please help me...
thank you

Comment: Check your PHP logs for errors?

Answer (score 0):

There are chanse to PHP Error Reporting is disable so no error are display.

can you please write this config.php file check error

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: thanx dear but  the problem is still there.... i have not access to checkout page.....ccavnue plugins deactivated then it work...why????

Comment: one more think ccavnue payment getaway plugins working on localhost(server)...... plz help me what can i do ....